# Widget in Ck-Editor is not retaining it's structure

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have defined a widget in a plugin of ck-editor.Code is like this -

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('simplebox', {

requires: 'widget',

icons: 'simplebox',

init: function(editor){
    //Plugin logic goes here
    editor.widgets.add('simplebox',{

        button:'create a simplebox',

        template:


                '<span class="left-bracket" display="inline">' +
                '[einstien]' +
                '</span>' 


    });
}
});
```

Now there are two problems -

1) It works fine initially.But once I click source toolbar button to see the html code and then revert back to editor mode, the widget loses it's structure and I can delete its elements one by one which was not happening before where on hitting backspace whole of the widget got cleared.

2) Ck-Editor documentation says that one can move around widget all over editor without losing it's structure.But I cannot move it.It seems fixed.

Also I have defined ***config.allowedContent = true;*** in config.js to avoid ACF rules.